# Is there a way to specify CSS specifically for Android

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, fonts, cordova

I'm working on a Phonegap app and having an issue with CSS line-height and margin rendering differently for a glyph font on my Android device as a compiled Phonegap application vs. Chrome on my desktop.

Is there a way to specify a CSS style specifically for Android's rendering engine only, similar to what you see commonly in CSS for cross-browser functionality (eg. -webkit, -moz, etc.)?

The font I'm using is http://www.entypo.com/ and the CSS styles I'm having problems with specifically are line-height and margin.  My regular fonts through-out the application are not  experiencing any issues like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can detect the device/environment your serving to then targeting elements specifically on that device is as simple as appending a class to the `<html>` tag of the page.  Then just call your style declarations from that root class.  For instance:

```
.wrapper {
    background: blue; /* will apply to all documents independent of device */
}

.android .wrapper {
    background: green; /* will only apply to documents with the .android base class */
}
```

As for detecting devices, that's an entirely different question, but this method will work assuming you can detect the device.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Based on your answer is it correct to assume that there is no way to declare a css style specifically for the Android rendering engine like you can for the various browsers?

Comment: Well, you're not really targeting a device per se, you're targeting that device's browser.  So if you know there's a limitation in that browser, and you know how to target that browser then you can apply specific styles with the method above.  But as far as I'm aware there is no 'Android' prefix for the Android/Google mobile browser.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I've implemented your solution and it's working like a charm.  Too bad there isn't a declaration in CSS for Android devices :).

Answer (score 0):

In your Android code, you can add to your `onCreate()` after you `loadUrl()`

```
this.sendJavascript("document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = 'android'");
```

This will add an "android" class to your `<body>` and let you use specific CSS selectors for your Android versions of the app. If you're already applying a class to your `<body>`, you can do

```
this.sendJavascript("document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className += ' android'");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Based on your answer is it correct to assume that there is no way to declare a css style specifically for the Android rendering engine like you can for the various browsers?

Comment: The closest you'd probably be able to get is by using -webkit, but as you've probably seen it would affect more than just Android. As far as I'm aware, there isn't a CSS selector specific to Android devices.